# GoogleAPI, Python: How to avoid getting ID of specified file in Google Drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I have this part of script which is listing files in my local folder, replaces old files in Google Drive by files from local folder and adds new files to Google Drive from local folder.

How to modify the script to check if there is file which is about to get added to GD because I have a kernel crash error in situation when: there is no file "A.csv" in GD, the script is uploading file "A.csv" - just after that I got kernel crash because the script is trying to get spreadsheetID of file which is not present in Google Drive yet. GetsppreadsheetID is defined in other part of script not mentioned here. Thank you for your help. I have no idea how to make additional "IF" to avoid getting spreadsheetID of file which has not been yet in Google Drive.

```
import gspread
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/krzysztofpaszta/credentials.json')
service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=gc.auth)
folder_id = '19vrbvaeDqWcxFGwPV82APWYTmBMEn-hi'  


def getSpreadsheetId(filename, filePath):
    q = "name='" + filename + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed=false"
    res = service.files().list(q=q, fields="files(id)", corpora="allDrives", includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
    items = res.get("files", [])
    if not items:
        print("No files found.")
        
        file_metadata = {
            "name": filename,
            "parents": [folder_id],
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
        }
        media = MediaFileUpload(filePath + "/" + filename + ".csv")
        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id", supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
        id = file.get("id")
        print("File was uploaded. The file ID is " + id)
        exit()
    return items[0]["id"]

filePath = '/users/krzysztofpaszta/CSVtoGD'
os.chdir(filePath)

files = os.listdir()
for filename in files:
    fname = filename.split(".")
    if fname[1] == "csv":
        oldSpreadsheetId = getSpreadsheetId(fname[0], filePath) - THIS PART NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
        sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)
        sh = gc.create(fname[0], folder_id)
        content = open(filename, "r").read().encode("utf-8")
        gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay first off i am not a python expert but I can see the issue.  In the sction of code below. You create the new file.  which returns to you a file id.

```
id = file.get("id")
```

Yet you are still returning

```
return items[0]["id"]
```

which is empty.

```
if not items:
    print("No files found.")
    
    file_metadata = {
        "name": filename,
        "parents": [folder_id],
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload(filePath + "/" + filename + ".csv")
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id", supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
    id = file.get("id")
    print("File was uploaded. The file ID is " + id)
    exit()
return items[0]["id"]
```

May i suggest something like this where if you do insert the file then you return the id to your code. while if the file exists you are returning the id from the response.

```
if not items:
    print("No files found.")
    
    file_metadata = {
        "name": filename,
        "parents": [folder_id],
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload(filePath + "/" + filename + ".csv")
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id", supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
    id = file.get("id")
    print("File was uploaded. The file ID is " + id)
    return id
else:
    return items[0]["id"]
```

If this doesn't work let me know i will boot up Pycharm and give it a shot.

Comment: @DalmTo thank you very much! As always I was trying to modify huge amount of lines but it was quite easy for you. It is working perfectly now. Thank you one more time :)

Comment: TBH I'm just impressed it worked im really not a Python developer :)